# How to get real type ratio between two time values?

Tags: vhdl

Having two `time` values in VHDL, for example:

```
constant t_1 : time :=   1 us;
constant t_2 : time := 300 ms;
```

How do I calculate the ratio between the two `time` values represented in `real` type?

The ratio, represented with ":", should for example give:

- t_1 : t_2 = 3.333333e-006
- t_2 : t_1 = 3.000000e+005

The challenge is that VHDL division of two physical types, like doing `t_1 / t_2`, returns an (universal) integer, thus with a result of 0 for `t_1 / t_2`, and not the desired values between 0.0 and 1.0.

The solution should be generally applicable, and also work for simulators having minimum time of more than `1 fs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modelsim has a `modelsim_lib.util` package with a `to_real()` function in it and Aldec has the same in `aldec.aldec_tools`.

If you need a portable solution that can be used in synthesis for generating constants, I have a [timing_ops package](http://code.google.com/p/vhdl-extras/source/browse/rtl/extras/timing_ops.vhdl) that contains a `to_real()` function along with a host of other time related utilities. The `to_real()` function makes an intermediate conversion to integer but intelligently handles large values of 64-bit time that exceed the range of the typical 32-bit integer by pre-scaling them. 64-bit integers are supported if available. The conversion function knows what the current time resolution is by using a modified version of the VHDL-2008 `resolution_limit` function. You will get the best accuracy in the integer conversion when the simulator resolution is as large as possible. At 1fs resolution you may lose some accuracy on large time values. It will preserve the maximum of 53-bits available in the IEEE 64-bit float significand when doing round trip conversion from time -> real -> time.

There are two versions of this package. The main one defines a physical type for frequency and works in Quartus and Vivado (and any simulator) but not XST. A stripped down [timing_ops_xilinx](http://code.google.com/p/vhdl-extras/source/browse/rtl/extras/timing_ops_xilinx.vhdl) removes the physical type to support XST. The logical package name remains `timing_ops` so your code can still be portable with only a change needed in library mapping.

Comment: Very nice collection functions in VHDL-extra.  But does it really require that amount of coding just to get a ratio between two values of time type?

Comment: If you don't need a general purpose solution you could take the ratio as `1.0 / real(300 ms / 1 us)` to get `t_1 / t_2`. This will fail if the numerator is more than 2**31 times greater than the denominator with 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to do such calculations but failed at some vendor tools ... My current solution is to use real constants for timings in ns or frequencies in MHz. If I need a concrete time I multiply the real constant with 1 ns which results in a time.

```
-- specify timing in microseconds
constant myTiming_us : real := 100.0;

-- scale timing and convert it to a time
constant myTime : time := 1 ns * myTiming_us * 1000.0;
```

### Edit 1:

Yay! I found my old bug/error notes why I'm not using time types directly ...

All notes below were tested in 2011 with Xilinx XST version O.61xd - If I remember correctly this was ISE 13.2.

Here are my notes:

```
-- type TIME is not supported in Xilinx Synthese Tools (XST) - Version O.61xd 2011
--  declaration of constants with type TIME => ERROR
--  usage of type TIME in functions         => ERROR

function kHz2Time(Freq_kHz : POSITIVE) return TIME is
begin
    return 1.0 ms / real(Freq_kHz);
end;

-- has no static result in Xilinx Synthese Tools (XST) - Version O.61xd 2011
function kHz2Time(Freq_kHz : REAL) return TIME is
begin
    return 1.0 ms / Freq_kHz;
end;

-- has no static result in Xilinx Synthese Tools (XST) - Version O.61xd 2011
function kHz2Time(Freq_kHz : REAL) return TIME is
  constant result : TIME := 1.0 ms / Freq_kHz;
begin
    return result;
end;
```

All 3 variants are commented (here uncommented to use syntax highlighting) and are not working in XST 13.2. If I remember correct, iSim 13.2 has no problems with this code.

### Edit 2:

I run my tests under ISE 14.7 again and as of now it seems to work correctly.
So the 'has no static result' issue is solved. Constants of type TIME can also be used in synthesis.

Moreover it's possible to define new physical times:

```
-- not yet supported by Xilinx Synthese Tools (XST) - Version 13.2 (O.61xd 2011)
type FREQ is range 0 to INTEGER'high units
    Hz;
    kHz = 1000 Hz;
    MHz = 1000 kHz;
    GHz = 1000 MHz;
end units;
```

The frequency to time conversion is a bit tricky:

```
function to_time(Frequency : FREQ) return TIME is
    variable Result : TIME;
begin
    assert MY_VERBOSE report "to_time: Frequency = " & FREQ'image(Frequency) severity note;

    if (Frequency < 1.0 kHz) then
        Result := (1.0 / real(Frequency / 1.0  Hz)) * 1.0 sec;
    elsif (Frequency < 1.0 MHz) then
        Result := (1.0 / real(Frequency / 1.0 kHz)) * 1.0 ms;
    elsif (Frequency < 1.0 GHz) then
        Result := (1.0 / real(Frequency / 1.0 MHz)) * 1.0 us;
    else
        Result := (1.0 / real(Frequency / 1.0 GHz)) * 1.0 ns;
    end if;

    assert MY_VERBOSE report "  return " & TIME'image(Result) severity note;
    return Result;
end function;
```

XST 14.7 and iSim 14.7 have no complains about this code any more.

Comment: That is a reasonable workaround, but it would be nice to use the physical type more, now that such is available in VHDL.

Comment: I have also a private VHDL package full of new physical types like _information_ or _memory_. This would allow users to specify memory sizes in KiB or MiB instead of 1024, or 1024 * 1024. Unfortunately XST does not support the definition of new physical types :( Maybe @Kevin-Thibedeau has added support for new physical types to GHDL. (?)

Comment: So, GHDL, Vivada Synthesis and Quartus II are also good with this code from Edit 1 and 2.